# How to use substring of result in PosrgreSQL/SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't know how to name this syntax properly. I got a table (say T) with column `A` in which store the entries in format `USER-YYYY-MMDD`. I want to extract all rows whose `A` column's year part (`YYYY` part) is greater than 2010. E.g.

```
TABLE T
+----------------+
|        A       |
+----------------+
| USER-2011-1234*|
| USER-1992-1923 |
| USER-2014-1234*|
+----------------+
```

(*) are what I want: `YYYY` part is greater than 2010. SQL should looks like this, but I dont know how to say it in PostgreSQL.

```
 SELECT * FROM T WHERE A[5-8] > 2010
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from t
where to_number(substr(a, 6, 4)) > 2010;
```

Note that his will fail with an error if the string cannot be converted to a number

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

Btw: storing more than one information in a single column is a bad design. You should store the username and the date in two different columns. Additionally storing dates as varchar is also a very bad idea. The date should be stored as `date` not as `varchar`

Comment: As a result of the problems mentioned in the post you have performance issue in your query as non-sargable predicate.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: as a workaround one, could create an index on `to_number(substr(a, 6, 4))`

Comment: Is the analogue of this in the mssql? Can you provide the link to documentation of this type of index. How it named? Index on expression?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan What's MS SQL got to do with this? In PostgreSQL, these are referred to as "functional indexes" or "expression indexes".

Comment: @CraigRinger MS SQL just forces to have well designed databases :)

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: even with a `date` column you might need an index on an expression if your expression contains a restriction only on the year. SQL Server doesn't force you any more than any other DBMS to have a well designed data model.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, If we have a `date` column we can write the predicate as `date_column > '20101231'`. It is sargable and no need of expression index.

Answer (score 2):

Try Like this

```
select *
from t
where  substring(a::text from 6 for 4)::integer > 2010;
```

Comment: It works. Thank you! Can you provide a link to the documentation for `::` stuff?